# get data from string to another strings

Tags: java, android, json, string

i'm getting http POST request and convert stream to string

```
result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
```

convert inputstream to String

```
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;
    inputStream.close();
    return result;
}
```

im getetting result format

```
{
    "id":"745741798",
    "name":"Oleg",
    "pswhash":"$2a$10$rC8",
    "phone":"+380 99 444 555",
    "email":"test@gmail.com",
    "status":"user",
    "regdate":"2015-10-30T17:52:53.076Z"
}
```

How to process result to
`String id = "745741798"; String name = "Oleg";`
etc.

Comment: This is JSON: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON and here is how you can parse it: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I have understood that you need to parse the values from the json.

For your case,

```
String jsonStr = "{
    "id":"745741798",
    "name":"Oleg",
    "pswhash":"$2a$10$rC8",
    "phone":"+380 99 444 555",
    "email":"test@gmail.com",
    "status":"user",
    "regdate":"2015-10-30T17:52:53.076Z"
}"
```

Create data model class as,

```
public class Data {
    String id;
    String name;
    String pswhash;
    String phone;
    String email;
    String status;
    Date regdate;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPswhash() {
        return pswhash;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public Date getRegdate() {
        return regdate;
    }

    public Class(String id, String name, String pswhash, String phone, String email, String status, Date regdate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.pswhash = pswhash;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.status = status;
        this.regdate = regdate;
    }
}
```

Then use [GSon](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson221jar.htm) for parsing,

```
Gson gson = new GSon();
Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Data.class);
```

After that, you can use like,

```
String id = data.getId();
String name = data.getName();
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at JSON libraries that can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jackson library: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/ or gson: https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

This is JSON string object and you can easily convert it into class object using GSON library of google.

Create Model class of your result with getter and setter method.

```
public class Result
{
private String id;

private String phone;

private String status;

private String email;

private String regdate;

private String name;

private String pswhash;

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPhone ()
{
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone (String phone)
{
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getStatus ()
{
    return status;
}

public void setStatus (String status)
{
    this.status = status;
}

public String getEmail ()
{
    return email;
}

public void setEmail (String email)
{
    this.email = email;
}

public String getRegdate ()
{
    return regdate;
}

public void setRegdate (String regdate)
{
    this.regdate = regdate;
}

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPswhash ()
{
    return pswhash;
}

public void setPswhash (String pswhash)
{
    this.pswhash = pswhash;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", phone = "+phone+", status = "+status+", email = "+email+", regdate = "+regdate+", name = "+name+", pswhash = "+pswhash+"]";
}
}
```

Convert your result string into Result class object like this.

```
Result result = gson.fromJson(resultJsonString, Result.class);
System.out.println(result.getId());
```